# Fill table in LaTeX using C#

Tags: c#, latex

Even though not an expert, I know little bit about operations in LaTeX. I want to begin writing  a paper in LaTeX. I have  done that using the following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Written using Latex}
\author{Guddi}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

But I have to now draw a table populated with huge data that comes as the ouput of a C# program in my case. Can I run LaTeX through C#? How to do that? Drawing a table in LaTeX is OK but doing it through a C# program is the problem for me.

Comment: I recommend you store the output from your program in a file, and generate the table in LaTeX.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Pls explain me

Comment: In your C# program, generate an output that is copy/pastable into your TeX file, and that would produce the desired table.

Comment: @guddi, I'm not that experienced with LaTeX, but i would store the output in a file as Comma-Separated Values (CSV). Then your table can be populated in LaTeX by reading the values. Here is a tutorial I found (haven't tried it myself, but it looks pretty straightforward):
http://texblog.org/2012/05/30/generate-latex-tables-from-csv-files-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written for you a sample function in C# that builds a table in LaTeX syntax:

```
private string createTable(string[] cols, string[][] values)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(@"\begin{table}[ht]");
    sb.AppendLine(@"\centering");
    // Assuming four columns.
    sb.AppendLine(@"\begin{tabular}{c c c c}");
    sb.AppendLine(@"\hline\hline");
    // Column headers.
    bool first = true;
    foreach (string col in cols)
    {
        if (!first)
            sb.Append(" & ");
        sb.Append(col);
        first = false;
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine(@"\hline");
    foreach (string[] rowCells in values)
    {
        first = true;
        foreach (string cell in rowCells)
        {
            if (!first)
                sb.Append(" & ");
            sb.Append(cell);
            first = false;
        }
        sb.AppendLine(@" \\");
    }
    sb.AppendLine(@"\hline");
    sb.AppendLine(@"\end{tabular}");
    sb.AppendLine(@"\end{table}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This code is based on this [reference](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/latex/TableHelp1.pdf). Alter the code for your convenience.